# Old school leather bag gloves

Tags: training, equipment

About 30 years ago, I had leather bag gloves made by Everlast that contained very little padding, but had thick leather and a heavy metal core in the palm.

Does any manufacturer still make something similar? I am not interested in the padded gloves, and I believe that the leather ones will hold up better than neoprene or other synthetics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's essentially a sales question.

Comment: There is a good question in there but as it stands, it is a sales question.

Comment: @SeanDuggan I don't see why a sales question is necessarily off-topic. This is about equipment, and equipment is expressly [on-topic](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The question is answerable and even verifiable.

Comment: @mattm: "use, maintenance, and construction" of equipment is on-topic. However, this is a "where can I buy this" question, which traditionally are not on-topic on Stack Exchange to my understanding.

Comment: I agree with @mattm; martial arts equipment is on-topic. "Martial arts equipment (**including** use, maintenance, and construction)" (my emphasis); this doesn't specifically exclude "where do I buy?" questions.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/TITLE-OLD-SCHOOL-HEAVY-GLOVES/dp/B00115RXT4/ref=sr_1_29/154-9652106-1602914?ie=UTF8&qid=1491073022&sr=8-29&keywords=leather+bag+gloves
Not sure if that is it, but it says old school in the name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up buy the [Hayabusa Fightwear Kanpeki Elite 3 4oz MMA Gloves](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B01HMS1MMC). Although they have some padding, they feel pretty good. I am still breaking them in.